# Peak detection and isolation in a noisy spectra [1D]

Tags: python, python-2.7, signal-processing

[peak Detect algorithm Reference](https://gist.github.com/endolith/250860): Thanks to @endolith

I am facing a problem with respect to peak trimming, based on the following algorithm I was able to find maxima and minimas of a certain spectra (peak). But what is the best method to choose the two minimas that are closer to the maxima, other words: trim it down.

There would be no problem if the peaks were perfect gaussian and I had to deal with just one central maxima and two extreme minimas. But since the peaks are not symmetric/ comes with noise; the challenge of having multiple maxima and minimas shall occur.

*Here is a small MWE (Minimal Working Example):*

```
import sys
from numpy import NaN, Inf, arange, isscalar, asarray, array


def peakdet_org(v, delta, x=None):
"""
Converted from MATLAB script at http://billauer.co.il/peakdet.html

Returns two arrays

function [maxtab, mintab]=peakdet(v, delta, x)
%PEAKDET Detect peaks in a vector
%        [MAXTAB, MINTAB] = PEAKDET(V, DELTA) finds the local
%        maxima and minima ("peaks") in the vector V.
%        MAXTAB and MINTAB consists of two columns. Column 1
%        contains indices in V, and column 2 the found values.
%      
%        With [MAXTAB, MINTAB] = PEAKDET(V, DELTA, X) the indices
%        in MAXTAB and MINTAB are replaced with the corresponding
%        X-values.
%
%        A point is considered a maximum peak if it has the maximal
%        value, and was preceded (to the left) by a value lower by
%        DELTA.

% Eli Billauer, 3.4.05 (Explicitly not copyrighted).
% This function is released to the public domain; Any use is allowed.

"""
maxtab = []
mintab = []

if x is None:
    x = arange(len(v))

v = asarray(v)

if len(v) != len(x):
    sys.exit('Input vectors v and x must have same length')

if not isscalar(delta):
    sys.exit('Input argument delta must be a scalar')

if delta <= 0:
    sys.exit('Input argument delta must be positive')

mn, mx = Inf, -Inf
mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN

lookformax = True

for i in arange(len(v)):
    this = v[i]
    if this > mx:
        mx = this
        mxpos = x[i]
    if this < mn:
        mn = this
        mnpos = x[i]

    if lookformax:
        if this < mx - delta:
            maxtab.append((mxpos, mx))
            mn = this
            mnpos = x[i]
            lookformax = False
    else:
        if this > mn + delta:
            mintab.append((mnpos, mn))
            mx = this
            mxpos = x[i]
            lookformax = True

return array(maxtab), array(mintab)


if __name__ == "__main__":
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot, scatter, show
#provide example Data:

yg = np.array([  1.57438571e+01,   7.61257196e+00,   1.52430926e-01,
     1.36516560e-01,   5.15979768e+00,   1.64124707e+01,
     1.89515520e+01,   1.42487909e+01,   3.54018477e+00,
     1.14062707e+01,   1.02388242e+01,   1.87826244e+01,
     1.95441484e+01,   2.24071140e+01,   2.02983868e+01,
     1.82032003e+01,   1.73453618e+01,   1.47026081e+01,
     1.78448059e+01,   2.58816032e+01,   6.56713725e+01,
     1.25462491e+02,   1.87772026e+02,   2.59049063e+02,
     3.51947933e+02,   4.53792943e+02,   5.19410345e+02,
     5.52208254e+02,   5.70822845e+02,   5.80361497e+02,
     5.89003135e+02,   6.06347208e+02,   6.43622339e+02,
     6.62009186e+02,   6.42148423e+02,   5.92902622e+02,
     5.20002943e+02,   4.41806277e+02,   3.48097035e+02,
     2.63343718e+02,   1.78357030e+02,   1.34485314e+02,
     1.17501271e+02,   1.09649638e+02,   8.43415105e+01,
     7.13899534e+01,   5.18412945e+01,   3.35901390e+01,
     2.08088661e+01,   3.07336351e+01,   4.79581429e+01])

series = yg
maxtab, mintab = peakdet_org(series, .3)
plot(series)
scatter(array(maxtab)[:, 0], array(maxtab)[:, 1], color='blue')
scatter(array(mintab)[:, 0], array(mintab)[:, 1], color='red')
show()
```

Example plot 1: Blues are Maximas, Reds are minimas
[image: Solution to MWE]

Example plot 2:
[image: Another variation]